# Cache for reverse geocoded data

Tags: caching, reverse-geocoding

How do I design a cache for reverse geo-coded data that I have.
i.e. Coordinates (Lat,Lon) -> Address

I need the cache to tell me if I have seen this address earlier (or an address that is fairly close) using the coordinates. The coordinates that I get might not be the EXACT coordinates that I saw earlier when I cached this data.

Is there a design scheme that people already use for something like this?

Comment: which prog. language are you using. in java you could create a class coordinates or call it coordinatespoint and create two members lat and long . the next step would request you to develop and hashcode and equals method which implementa same latitudes and longitudes to be the same. Now you can use this class as hashmap type and your data would be stored. the hasmap would use the instance as key and the vavlie would be ise reverse